# Cannot shutdown ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia

I am using ubuntu 16.04 (64bit AMD) on my laptop (Asus brand, chip intel, card Nvidia, 8GB RAM) and I have a problem when shutting down Ubuntu, my laptop hangs on as soon as power off command, I can't do anything except with power button :(.
I searched and try some a solution such as a config acpi=force, DefaultTimeoutStopSec=5s ..., but it not working.
Anything I can do with my problem?

Comment: Typing `ESC` during shutdown should show you where the shutdown is hanging.

Comment: i cannot typing any button